# Bootstrap Table: Excel Accounting Format

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accounting

I am trying to replicate the Excel accounting format in a Bootstrap table, whereas the currency sign in aligned to the far left, and the digits to the far right.

I have tried:

```
<td>$ <span class="text-right">123456</span></td>
```

But it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, please find the number formatting you’re looking for.  The {{}} are blade notation for PHP statements.

```
<td><span style="float:right">{{ ($i==1) ? '$' : '' }}{{number_format($e['price_sale'], 2, '.', ',')}}</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<td><span class="text-left">$ </span><span class="text-right">123456</span></td>
```